# Something removed a user's group memberships - How can I prevent this in the future?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, groups

I had a user say that he wasn't getting emails, so I got on the DC and made sure his account didn't have any obvious issues. I just happened to click on the `Member of` tab and saw that he was not a member of any group!

I added him back to the appropriate groups and all is good, but I would like to know what might have happened and if I can do anything to stop this from happening in the future.

Comment: I'm going to say this Matt, but I mean no offense. If you're going to be a sysadmin then start learning and using the correct terminology. You can't check a user's profile from a DC unless that user has logged onto the DC. A user *profile* and a user *account* are two different things. You checked the user account, not the user profile. When you say **user profile** I think of certain things and when you say **group membership** I think of certain other things. To get an accurate answer you need to have an accurate question. I could be wrong though if the user is in fact logging  onto the DC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple: Someone or something removed him from these groups. This doesn't happen automatically and I've never seen an AD failure that's caused this - it was either an error from another administrator, or an automated process gone awry, such as a script.

There's likely nothing you can do now, but in the future you can [audit Directory Services changes](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd941584(v=ws.10).aspx).

Comment: Thank you Sir!  I will get on that immediately.  I appreciate you pointing me in the right direction, in such a polite and positive manor.  Enjoy your day!